Circular progress bar is not animating in Firefox, but it working in Chrome
I am trying to build a circular progress bar that will countdown as it reaches 100%. The element is supposed to be dynamic such that if you pass it in a second, it will render the countdown timer for that duration.
I have this animation working fine in Chrome, but it is failing to animate in Firefox.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sample Ciruclar Progress Countdown</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .circular-progress {
            --size: 250px;
        --half-size: calc(var(--size) / 2);
            --stroke-width: 20px;
        --radius: calc((var(--size) - var(--stroke-width)) / 2);
            --circumference: calc(var(--radius) * pi * 2);
            --dash: calc((var(--progress) * var(--circumference)) / 100);
            animation: progress-animation 5s linear 1s 1 forwards !important;
        }

        .circular-progress circle {
            cx: var(--half-size);
            cy: var(--half-size);
            r: var(--radius);
            stroke-width: var(--stroke-width);
            fill: none;
            stroke-linecap: round;
        }

        .circular-progress circle.bg {
            stroke: #ddd;
        }

        .circular-progress circle.fg {
            transform: rotate(-90deg);
            transform-origin: var(--half-size) var(--half-size);
            stroke-dasharray: var(--dash) calc(var(--circumference) - var(--dash));
            stroke: blue;
            transition: stroke-dasharray 0.3s linear 0s;
        }
        .countdown {
            color: #5394fd;
        }
        @property --progress {
            syntax: "<number>";
            inherits: false;
            initial-value: 0;
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes progress-animation {
            from {
                --progress: 0;
            }
            to {
                --progress: 100;
            }
        @-moz-keyframes progress-animation {
            from {
                --progress: 0;
            }
            to {
                --progress: 100;
            }
        }
        @keyframes progress-animation {
            from {
                --progress: 0;
            }
            to {
                --progress: 100;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="circular-progress-description">
    <p>Estimated wait time: <span class="duration">5</span> seconds.</p>
    <svg width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250" id="circular-progress" class="circular-progress">
        <circle class="bg"></circle>
        <circle class="fg"></circle>
        <text id="countdown" x="125" y="125" text-anchor="middle" dy="7" font-size="20"></text>
    </svg>
</div>

</body>
<script>
    (function() {
        let duration = 10;
        console.log(`Running for ${duration} seconds`)
        const progressBar = document.getElementById("circular-progress");
        document.getElementsByClassName("duration")[0].innerHTML=`${duration}`;
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML=`${duration}`;
        progressBar.style.animationDuration = `${duration}s`;
        progressBar.style.animationName = `MyAnimations`;
        progressBar.style.MozAnimationName  = `MyAnimations`;
        progressBar.style.playState  = `running`;
        $('#circular-progress').css('animation-duration', '10s');
        progressBar.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
            location.reload(true);
        });
    })();

</script>
</html>

I tried adding -webkit -moz, but it did not help. I am unable to get it to work with Firefox.

check the developer tools console for errors,. specifically CSS errors regarding @property - or if that's too hard, read this

Firefox still has no support for @property and animating CSS variables

missing } to close @-webkit-keyframes progress-animation {

Why was it approved with such glaring deficiencies? There isn't even a question in there.

As commented before support for @property is still a bit "wobbly". But you can easily simplify your code by also taking advantage of SVG's pathLength attribute – admittedly it's not a presentation attribute so you can't set it via CSS rules. In short you can normalize the scale/total range to e.g 100 and control the progress as well by changing a CSS variable. See simplified codepen example
